# exponential decay as input goes to 0

Tags: exponential-function

I don't know why but i'm having trouble figuring this out. I'm trying to find an exponential growth function where the value grows exponentially as it goes from any positive number and approaches a limit of zero. Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: Do you want the value to "grow" exponentially or "decay" exponentially?

Comment: the output should grow exponentially as the input gets closer to 0

Comment: Then $e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ does the trick.